# No provider for FormGroupDirective in Angular 2 nested custom component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular 2 RC.5 I cannot find a fix for the mentioned error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
No provider for FormGroupDirective ("p>Custom begin </p>
      <p>Host contains {{hostFormGroup.directives.length}} directives</p>
      [ERROR ->]<nested></nested>
      <p>Custom end </p>
    </div>
"): CustomComponent@4:6 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

happening when a custom component, nested within another custom component, has a dependency on containing `@Host() hostFormGroup: FormGroupDirective`.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jZZkD?p=preview) showing the scenario. *AppComponent* shows a reactive/model-driven form (temporarily without controls, but that's not crucial at this point) containing *CustomComponent*, which in turn has a *NestedComponent*. See developer console for error details.

First-level custom component can have a dependency on hosting *FormGroupDirective* or not, it does not affect the issue. If it has the dependency, that is resolved correctly. The same does not happen for second-level custom component, no matter what in first-level component.

The problem goes away if the same *NestedComponent* is used directly in *AppComponent*.

What am I missing? TA

Here's main part of code, for reference:

```ts
import { Component, Host } from '@angular/core';
import {
  REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,
  FormGroup, FormGroupDirective
} from '@angular/forms';

///////////////////////
// Nested

@Component({
  selector: 'nested',
  template: `
    Nested begin<br/>
    Nested end <br/>
  `,
})
class NestedComponent {
  constructor(
    @Host() private hostFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {
  }
}

///////////////////////
// Custom

@Component({
  selector: 'custom',
  template: `
    Custom begin <br/>
    <nested></nested> <br/>
    Custom end <br/>
  `,
  directives: [NestedComponent],
})
class CustomComponent {
  constructor(
    @Host() private hostFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {
  }
}

///////////////////////
// App

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Angular 2 - @Host() issue</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="mainForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
    <fieldset>
      <custom></custom>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  `,
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, CustomComponent],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.mainForm = formBuilder.group({});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the @Host() decorators and the extra providers and it works.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'nested',
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Nested begin </p>
      <p>Host contains {{hostFormGroup.directives.length}} directives:</p>
      <span *ngFor="let directive of hostFormGroup.directives">{{directive.name}}</span>
      <p>Nested end </p>
    </div>
  `,
  // tried this: no error, but injected one is not the actual container
  // and it containes no directive
  // without it: still same error 'No provider for FormGroupDirective'
  //providers: [FormGroupDirective],
})
class NestedComponent {
  constructor(
    private hostFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {
  }
}
// Custom

@Component({
  selector: 'custom',
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Custom begin </p>
      <p>Host contains {{hostFormGroup.directives.length}} directives:</p>
      <span *ngFor="let directive of hostFormGroup.directives">{{directive.name}}</span>
      <nested></nested>
      <p>Custom end </p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [NestedComponent],
  // tried this: still same error 'No provider for FormGroupDirective'
  //providers: [FormGroupDirective],
})
class CustomComponent {
  constructor(
    private hostFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ktvnjm?p=preview

Comment: Github issue is now closed. From there: Has @Host() been deprecated or has something changed? In case, do you know where to find more info on this? With my team I could not find any, @Host() reference doc is still there, and as far as I remember that was the way to access outer container.

Comment: How can I implement in that case if I have on the subform more input fields?

Comment: If I have more input fields on the nested, as I think I cannot use the nested when I create the custom form with FormBuilder because in the nested, add the formcontrols dinamically. Is it correct?

Answer (score 8):

The error message kind of points you in the right direction.  You need to declare that the `FormGroupDirective` is a provider.  i.e.

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [FormGroupDirective]
});
```

Otherwise, you need to declare it at a higher level in, such as in your module, so you can use it Module wide.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried during other tests before, I think I was trying with a *FormGroup*, and adding that to provider list did not help (it complained about not being able to construct that, or some missing c'tor params, don't remember precisely), so I excluded that trick with *FormGroupDirective* as well. But then again, why it is not needed when component is at first-level below *AppComponent*?

Comment: Apart from last question, this edit does not solve the issue. If I add that provider within *NestedComponent* the error disappears, but the injected instance is useless. It's not the actual hosting instance, but just a newed up one. In actual project, nested component needs the actual containing form. If instead I add that provider at a higher level, again I see that console error.

Comment: Just to double check what you've done, you get the error even when you import it at the Module level?  That shouldn't be the case as any provider imported at the module level is used module wide, you no longer have to add it as a provider at the component level, just instantiate it in the constructor

Comment: I'm not sure this is the way to go. That *@Host*-decorated dependency is not looking for "a generic instance" of *FormGroupDirective*, or for a singleton instance of that, as generally happens for injected services. That decorator instructs angular to inject the hosting form-group. When you have e.g. two *NestedComponent* instances in two different forms, they should get the two distinct form groups injected. Not some provided instance.